# error downloading libsane-dev message reads:

Tags: 16.04

Some months ago my scanner stopped working with the message that I need to install driver software.  My printer is a HP Officejet 6210 All-in-one.  So have attempted to load HPLIP 3.18.6 but get the error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libsane-dev : Depends: libsane (= 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1) but 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libsane libsane-dev` to the question. Did you forget to run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: output as requested: system says to long please advise how reply to question

Comment: this site is to difficult for this senior  not straight forward , I give up

Comment: Then you can try to use http://pastebin.com/ to show output of commands.

Answer (score -1):

The previously installed libsane-dev package seems to be broken.

Try re-installing the package. Use

> sudo apt purge libsane-dev

to uinstall the package.

and re-install using

> sudo apt-get install libsane-dev.